# how can i make grep extract string by length in bash?

Tags: sorting, grep

I want to be able to extract a word thats a specific length in a wordlist and extract it to another list.

If i run:

```
grep -oP '\b(\w{7})\b' infile >> outfile
```

eveything run fine and the words get extracted but when i run it in a bash script, nothing gets outputted. if i put double quotes as it was causing the length number from being read, i still get syntax error.so the script looks like this:

```
read -p "what is in:" in
read -p "what is out:" out
read -p "what is char num:" char

grep -oP '\b(\w{$char})\b' $in >> $out
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Please show desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have double quotes so that bash expands variables in strings

Try

```
grep -oP "\b(\w{$char})\b"
```

---

Seeing it in action:

Input file

```
$ cat file1
dockerkill container
docker anothercontainer
dockerput contain
```

Script:

```
$ cat script.sh
char="6"
grep -oP "\b(\w{$char})\b" file1
```

Output

```
$ ./script.sh
docker
```